# run web application with context entry in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have tomcat which successfully running web application with just making following entry into `conf/server.xml` file.

```
<Host name="test" debug="0" appBase="full path of jsp and java classes"
                unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false">

                <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger"
                    prefix="om_log." suffix=".log"
                    timestamp="true"/>

        <Context path="" docBase="full path of jsp and java classes"
               reloadable="false" crossContext="false" />
    </Host>
```

But i am not able to run same thing in newly downloaded tomcat.

Cal i know the step to run application with context entry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [Context docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) on Tomcat website

> Defining a context It is NOT recommended to place `<Context>` elements
>   directly in the `server.xml` file. This is because it makes modifying
>   the Context configuration more invasive since the main `conf/server.xml`
>   file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.
>
> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> 1. In an individual file at `/META-INF/context.xml` inside the application
>      files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be
>      copied to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` and renamed to
>      application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.
> 2. In individual
>      files (with a ".xml" extension) in the
>      `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory. The context
>      path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the
>      file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take
>      precedence over any `context.xml` file packaged in the web application's
>      META-INF directory.
> 3. Inside a `Host` element in the main `conf/server.xml`.

Without knowing exactly what error you get, it's hard to help any more than this.